# simple product image in kart with configurable swatches

Tags: rwd-theme

first of all, please excuse me for my english, i will do my best to be understandable.

the issue is with the configurale swatches extend : I have configured everything as explained and it works well but I have no change of image in the kart.

Is it something known??

Is it a mistake from me?

Is there a solution?

Comment: Can you explain what you did? "I configured everything as explained" doe snot mean much.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is possible with the Mage_ConfigurableSwatches module released in **CE 1.9.1** out of the box.

1. Go to: `System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart`
2. Set the `Configurable Product Image` option to `Product Thumbnail
   Itself`

> Note: It is important that you upload an image for the **child product** for this to work

I have tested this and got this running for my own store, no custom development needed!

Comment: thank you for your answer, i had found also this and it fully works. There is indeed no need to develop anything else.

Comment: Your welcome @bigbert! Glad you got this working now. Please don't forget to mark my answer as the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the configured item from your cart and then call the getImage function on the configured child.  It's not too hard.